# Docker 'killing' my program

Tags: docker

I am running a data analysis code in docker using pandas on MacOS.
However, the program gets killed on high memory allocation in a data frame (I know because it gets killed when my program is loading a huge dataset).
Without the container, my program runs alright on my laptop.

Why is this happening and how can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker on MacOS is running inside a Linux VM which has an explicit memory allocation. From [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#advanced):

> **MEMORY**
>
> By default, Docker for Mac is set to use 2 GB runtime memory,
>   allocated from the total available memory on your Mac. You can
>   increase the RAM on the app to get faster performance by setting this
>   number higher (for example to 3) or lower (to 1) if you want Docker
>   for Mac to use less memory.

Those instructions are referring to the [Preferences](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#preferences) dialog.